# How can We set and get System propertiesi in Android Q

Tags: java, android

I want to set these 3 properties.

1. System.setProperty("persist.sys.usb.config", "diag,adb,serial_smd,serial_tty,rmnet,mass_storage");
2. System.setProperty("sys.usb.config", "diag,adb,serial_smd,serial_tty,rmnet,mass_storage");
3. System.setProperty("persist.sys.usb.config.extra", "diag");

Can We use reflection concept in Q?.
Please say How to set and get System Properties. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "System property" - this can be anything from battery optimization to simple reading out whether in flight mode or not... List specific what you want to read and/or write and show code what you have tried so far.

Comment: since when you can't use reflection concept in Q?

Comment: Do you mean build.prop ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and you shouldn't viewing the source code in here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/eclair-release/core/java/android/os/SystemProperties.java

SystemProperties is annotated with @hide that means it's not in the official API

only one way to that is by reflection or by getting the source, removing @hide and making your own customized SDK.

However, you can use double reflection https://www.xda-developers.com/android-development-bypass-hidden-api-restrictions/